# How to tell CMake not to cache variables

Tags: cmake

I am using CMake in to custom create files on the fly from files that exist in a specified location. This is my code:

```
file(GLOB files "${path}/*.data")
file(GLOB sidedata "${path}/*.sidedata")

foreach(file ${files})
   get_filename_component(name ${file} NAME_WE)
   add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${name}.library"
      DEPENDS ${path} ${file} ${sidedata} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/makelibrary.pl
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/makelibrary.pl ARGS ${sidedata} ${file}
      COMMENT "Generating ${name}.library"
   )
   add_custom_target(${name}.target ALL DEPENDS ${name}.library)
   install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${name}.library DESTINATION ${somewhere})
endforeach()
```

The issue I am seeing that the `files` and `sidedata` are cached - if a new file is added to `path` location it will not be detected; if a file is removed, the dependency check fails.

How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: The variables don't get cached by doing `file(GLOB...)` - are you sure they're actually added to your CMakeCache.txt file in your build root?  Are you hoping to have an added file automatically detected by CMake without manually re-running CMake?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to have CMake add a file. Is the solution as simple as re-running just `cmake <path>` inside my build area to get the new files and remove old ones? I tried that, seemed to do what I want.

Comment: Yup - that would do it.  It's not great - if you forget to rerun CMake it'll be painful :-)  You *could* look at adding the `file(GLOB...)` commands to a separate CMake script which gets invoked via `add_custom_target`.  The custom target would run `cmake -P` on this script, and it would always be executed - the list of files would be updated every time you built.  It's a bit convoluted though :)

Comment: Thanks! I am perfectly content with rerunning `cmake ...`. Incidentally my automated build already does that (I was wondering why it hasn't failed), so it is a matter of the developers doing it only when something fails.

Answer (score 2):

Just to close this question, I followed the Fraser's suggestion : rerun plain `cmake <source area>` to update the file list.
Also, the variables were not in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the module `CheckCXXSourceRuns` like this

```
include(CheckCXXSourceRuns)
check_cxx_source_runs("
#include ...
int main() {
    ...
}" HAVE_AVX_EXTENSIONS)
```

To force CMake to reevaluate this on every call to `cmake ..`, I am calling  `cmake .. -U HAVE_\*`. This will undefine the `HAVE_` variables, so that CMake has to reevaluate them.

Source: https://blogs.kde.org/2011/02/05/how-selectively-remove-entries-cmake-cache-command-line